# Magento SOAP 500 Internal Error Response

Tags: magento-1.7, php, soap, soap-api-v2

I'm getting a 500 internal error response when I try to retrieve data via SOAP.

What I have that's working and not giving me 500 internal error:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('xxx', 'xxx');
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,configurable')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value->product_id;
    echo $id;
   // productPrices($id); <-- this issue causes the error.
}



?>
```

When I then try to call a funtion in the foreach loop (see comment above):

```
function productPrices($id){
    $client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $session = $client->login('xxx', 'xxx');
    $att = array("visibility","sku","special_price", "price");
    $arguments = array( $id, NULL, $att);
    $resultPrice = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $arguments);
    echo $resultPrice['visibility'].",".$resultPrice['sku'].",".$resultPrice['special_price'].",".$resultPrice['price'];
}
```

The response I get from the server is now internal error 500. I have maximum 90 sku's/product ids.

Anyone know what the error might be?

Comment: please increase max_execution_time & memory_limit in your server

Answer (score 1):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
class Foo_Bar {
    $_client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $_session = $client->login('xxx', 'xxx');

public function productPrices($id) {
    $client = $this->_client;
    $session = $client->login('xxx', 'xxx');
    $att = array("visibility","sku","special_price", "price");
    $arguments = array( $id, NULL, $att);
    $resultPrice = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $arguments);
    echo $resultPrice['visibility'].",".$resultPrice['sku'].",".$resultPrice['special_price'].",".$resultPrice['price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working as is, something is missing as the php code fails of the top. Showing blank page.

Comment: What happens when you access `http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl` via browser? Also check your web servers `error.log` file for more insight to the 500 error.

Comment: As described there is no issue I get the full output from the store on soap url.

Comment: When I call the function in the foreach loop - I write :    productPrices->Foo_Bar($id); 
 isen't that correct?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html should give you a working example to try.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Magento threw an Exception wich result in Internal Server Error.
For me helped that I log all exceptions that are thrown by adding

```
self::log(debug_backtrace()[0]['file'].":".debug_backtrace()[0]['line']." - ".$message, 1, 'exceptions.log');
```

before the line `throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message);` in the `throwException` Method in `app/Mage.php` file

Hope that help you find your specific error

Answer (score 1):

**Logs**

Please see log files for more information:

- Magento logs `<magento_root>/var/log/*` - especially `system.log` and `exception.log`
- See also whether new report files were created `<magento_root>/var/report/`
- Webserver logs `/var/log/nginx/(error|access).log` or in case you use Apache `/var/log/(apache|httpd)/*.log`
- PHP(-fpm) logs - often here `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`

**SSL**

The default behaviour of the SoapClient is different to browsers behaviour. Especially following redirects, etc... Is `http` correct? Maybe you need https?

**Webserver configuration**

Maybe your webserver is configured to accept only browser requests. E.g. by UserAgent rules...? Or the API route has special protection.